# Span with Number not Displaying in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pug

```
md-tab
    md-tab-label
        span Comments
        span.tab-number {{page.comments.total}}
```

I am using AngularJS and Pug. This makes a span with "Comments" in it, and displays the number of comments next to that. It works in Chrome, but in Firefox, only the span with "Comments" is displayed. I did research on these types of things but only found people having issues with User Input w/ input type as number in Firefox. Apparently Firefox does not support that input type. These people used someone's number-polyfill solution here (https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill).

I don't know how this might help me, but does anybody have an idea of how I can display the number of comments in the span.tab-number?

Right now, in place of the number, there is a "...".

Thank you

Comment: The PUG tag wiki reads "Pug ... is a ... template engine for Node.js", but you appear to be using it client-side. Is that correct?

Comment: Sounds like a css issue. Inspect element in browser dev tools and see what it actually contains and what css rules apply to it

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Yes this is client-side. Sorry if I was misleading. I did inspect charlietfl, and it shows the HTML-converted code of what it was supposed to be with the "Comments" and "8".  I will check the css rules in the two browsers and compare (firefox vs chrome). Thanks

Comment: Got it working @charlietfl thanks for the tip, hadn't thought of that